# How to optimize a Python script for inserting data into a database and pushing data to an AWS SQS queue with large datasets?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, concurrency

I have a python script which reads data from a CSV and performs 2 tasks for each row:

1. Inserts the row into a table in PostgreSQL database.
2. Push the row to an AWS SQS queue.

This script performs well when I have a small dataset of ~1-10k records. But as the size of my dataset increases. The script execution time increases exponentially.

I did some benchmarking and realised that: In order to insert in database and push to queue, when the dataset contains ~1M records. My script takes >100 Minutes to complete.

I did some digging and found that my DB inserts are much faster than pushing to queue.

I thought `asyncio` would solve my problem if I synchronously inserted into the database and asynchronously pushed to the queue. But what it does is something that I cant use: It batches all the asynchronous requests in an array and after the synchronous task is completed, starts executing the async tasks. This is a no no for me because I will be running this script in a serverless environment. Where the execution will be stopped after database insertions are finished.

An ideal scenario for me would be: If I'm able to run run database insertions on one tread and queue push on another, which I know is not possible in Python.

Is there any other way or pattern that would help in my case. Any kind of suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help you speed up things: [https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs/client/send_message_batch.html]
It allows to send messages in batches

Comment: More long term solution, maybe to e.g. upload you file to S3 which will trigger lambda function to do this job

Comment: It is _much_ more efficient to insert multiple rows into a database in a single INSERT, rather than one row per INSERT. Which database are you using? Similarly, using `SendMessageBatch` to send 10 messages to an SQS queue is _much_ more efficient than sending a single message.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein My dataset contains time series data. Which means row1 can have data of a user and then row2 can have data of the same user but with updated values. So I have query the db on every row and identify the delta (if any). Which is why Im doing this iteratively. BTW: Im using PostgreSQL

Comment: Could you share your python code?  Maybe there is some inefficiency you have built in by accident.  Also, what component is consuming from the SQS queue?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of researching and trying different solutions to see which one works the best. I ended up taking a different approach all together. Rather than doing an insert and then after the insert was completed pushing data to queue.

In this approach I load the data from PySpark dataframe into a temp table. Then I wrote a procedure that compares the main table and the temp table for any difference.

Here's how my procedure looks like

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table_temp
EXCEPT
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table_main
```

I insert the response of this query into the main table using `UPDATE ON CONFLICT` like this

```sql
INSERT INTO table_main (col1, col2, col3)
  SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3
  FROM (
     SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table_temp
     EXCEPT
     SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table_main
  ) AS a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table_main ON a.id = table_main.id
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET col1 = EXCLUDE.col1,
    col2 = EXCLUDE.col2,
    col3 = EXCLUDE.col3;
```

This way I insert all the new records and update existing record if there is a conflict.

After running this procedure, I push all the records return by the `EXCEPT` query to queue using [python workers](https://superfastpython.com/threadpool-worker-initializer/#:%7E:text=Tasks%20are%20issued%20to%20the,completing%20tasks%20in%20the%20pool.) this way even I am able to push to SQS from multiple workers making the whole process `number of workers` times faster.